# Interface PID temperature control module using Arduino

Tags: arduino, temperature, pid-controller, modbus

I need to interface a modular type temperature controller using Arduino.
This is the [datasheet](http://eng.hynux.com/iframe_view1.php?down=1039.pdf&file_name=MA0616E170425_MLseries.pdf&size=3471522&board_name=Bdatafile/Board) of temperature controller

The datasheet mentioned like this,
[image: Protocol composition]

My questions are,
How can I interface( Reading/Writing parameters) to the controller using Arduino?
Is there any library for achieve this communication?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to talk with the sensor. For that you need a UART to RS232 converter of a UART to RS485 converter. A good one is the MAX232.

The second step is to find a library that support one of the protocols or write your own library. This can be achieved by searching on google.